# Como passar um determinado contéudo contido em uma primeira activity direto para uma terceira activity?

Tags: android, android-studio, intent, android-intent

Galera gostaria de saber como faço para passar o conteúdo de uma plainText que se encontra na MainActivity direto para a Main3Activity, sem ter de importar também para a Main2Activity para depois para a Main3Activity.

**O usuário passa na Main2Activity antes de ir para a Main3Acitvity.**

Na **MainActivity** tem um plainText (etPlanetaVive) onde o usuário informa qual o planeta onde ele vive.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

MainActivity.java

```js
ackage genesysgeneration.third;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

    private EditText etPlantaVive;
    private Button btnNext_01;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        etPlantaVive=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.etPlanetaVive);

        btnNext_01=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnNext_01);
        btnNext_01.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    public void onClick(View v){

        Intent it = new Intent(this, Main2Activity.class);
        it.putExtra("planetaVive", etPlantaVive.getText().toString());
        startActivity(it);

    }

}
```

Eu exporto o contéudo da plainText para a Main2Activity através do código `it.putExtra("planetaVive", etPlantaVive.getText().toString());`

Na **Main2Activity** tem um plainText onde o usuário informa qual o planeta onde ele gostaria de viver.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Main2Activity.java

```js
package genesysgeneration.third;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

    private String planetaVive;
    private EditText etPlanetaDesejo;
    private Button btnNext_02;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        planetaVive = getIntent().getStringExtra("planetaVive");

        etPlanetaDesejo=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.etPlanetaDesejo);
        btnNext_02=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnNext_02);
        btnNext_02.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    public void onClick(View v){

        Intent it = new Intent(this, Main3Activity.class);
        it.putExtra("planetaVive", planetaVive);
        it.putExtra("planetaDesejo", etPlanetaDesejo.getText().toString());
        startActivity(it);

    }

}
```

Gostaria de não ter de importar para a segunda activity o conteúdo da primeira **plainText (etPlanetaVive)** => `planetaVive = getIntent().getStringExtra("planetaVive");` Gostaria de ter que fazer isso somente na terceira (Main3Activity).

Na Main3Activity aparece isso:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Main3Activity.java

```js
package genesysgeneration.third;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Main3Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private String planetaVive, planetaDesejo;
    private TextView tvFinalPlanetaVive, tvFinalPlanetaDesejo;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main3);

        planetaVive = getIntent().getStringExtra("planetaVive");
        planetaDesejo = getIntent().getStringExtra("planetaDesejo");

        tvFinalPlanetaVive=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvFinalPlanetaVive);
        tvFinalPlanetaVive.setText(tvFinalPlanetaVive.getText().toString() + planetaVive);

        tvFinalPlanetaDesejo=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvFinalPlanetaDesejo);
        tvFinalPlanetaDesejo.setText(tvFinalPlanetaDesejo.getText().toString() + planetaDesejo);

    }
}
```

Como viram tive de passar o conteúdo da primeira activity para a segunda, para somente depois passar para a terceira.

Answer (score 1):

É só salvar tudo numa classe estática.

```
public class Dados{

            public String txtAct1 = null;
            public static Dados instancia = null;

    public Dados getInstancia(){
           if(instancia==null){
           instancia = new Dados();
        }
           return instancia;
    }

    public void setTxtAct1(String txtAct1 ){
        this.txtAct1 = txtAct1;
    }

    public String getTxtAct1(){
        return txtAct1;
    }
 }
```

Depoiis é só ir estocando os dados com `Dados.getInstancia.setTxtAct1("terra");` (logicamente voce vai criar a quantidade de strings que desejar e seus gets e sets respectivos) e recuperar com `String act1 = Dados.getInstancia.getTxtAct1;`